# I'm making a project for fun, a movie site(not actually gonna use it, just testing how far I could go with my basic knowledge and the internet)

Tags: html, css, project

So I ran into a bit of a problem with the css, I made a div and inside that div is a link that takes over one whole line even thought its not as big as the whole line, whenever I try to add something it pushes it into the next line instead of putting the link on the same line next to each other. How could I possibly make it stick on the same line (already tried display: inline; and display: inline-block;) Here is the code...I know its a mess I'm new to this :D.

Here is the code of my first page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>VASMOVIES</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vas.css"/>
<script defer src="http://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="div1">
<h1 title="Home"><a href="home.html"> VASMOVIES </a></h1>
</div>

</header>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h1 class="center"> VASMOVIES </h1>
<div class="search-box">
<input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search for movies">
<a class="search-btn" href="#">
<i class="fas fa-search"></i>
</a>
</div>

<footer>
<button class="button" onclick="darkmode()">Dark/Light mode</button>

<button class="button"><a href="emailpage.html">Contact me</button>
<script>
function darkmode() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
</script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    transition: 1s;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #121212;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.button {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
.button:hover {
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    background-color: #333;
}
.dark-mode {
    transition: 1s;
    background-color: #CAF4F4;
    color: black;
}

.center {
    color: purple;
    text-align: center;
}
.div1 {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 50%;
    
}

.div2 {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 50%;
    color: darkgray;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    line-height: 0.1;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: purple;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:active {
    color: purple;
}
footer {
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
}



.search-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 35%;
    transfor: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #333;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.search-box:hover > .search-txt {
    
}
.search-btn {
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2f3640;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.search-txt {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    color: #808080;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```html
<div class="div1">
<h1 title="Home"><a href="home.html"> VASMOVIES </a></h1>
</div>
```

If so, what do you mean when you say you add something to it?

Comment: What I meant to say was, when I add for example another <h1> text </h1> it automatically puts it in next line or row instead of putting it next "VASMOVIES" on the page

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you was trying to acheive?

[image]

If so you can use the display: inline; CSS class. You have to apply it like so:

```html
<div class="div1">
<h1 title="Home" style="display: inline;">
  <a href="home.html" style="display: inline;"> VASMOVIES </a></h1>
 <h1 style="display: inline;">Text</h1>
</div>
```

The CSS does not have to be inline, but I think you understand the example.

Comment: Yes! Exactly that. thank you very much!

Comment: @Vaske if it was the solution you should mark it as so on the left side of my answer :)

Comment: I would love to and I have tried, but it seems I need at least 15 reputation to be able to cast a vote and I am new to this so I have no reputation...